# How can I let users change headers by entering amount in a text box?

Tags: c#, winforms

What do I have to put in the private void textbox to make a user enter a amount and that amount will be applied to where await `Connection.SendToServerAsync(2700, 790);` is now. so let's say a user enters `2000`, `8` in the texbox, then the `(2700,790)` has to change to `(2000, 8)`

```
namespace Application
{
    public partial class Form1 : ExtensionForm
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int repeat = 5;

            for (int i = 0; i <= repeat; i++)
            {
                await Connection.SendToServerAsync(2700, 790);
                await Connection.SendToServerAsync(3745);
            }
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the textbox value using [`TextBox.Text`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.text(v=vs.110).aspx).

It comes as a `string`, so you have to convert to `int`. You can do that using one of the following:

- [`Int.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`Convert.ToInt32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b(v=vs.110).aspx)

With the converted value you can just call the methods with the new values when the button is clicked.

Comment: I'm sorry but could you make those changes in my code and post it? I have been working with C# for 5 hours so I don't really know where to put things when I first hear them